# My linked list code in c++ is only appending one value

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I study the data structure module and I have my linked list code written from the book . While I run the code it's just append one node and while calling the displayNode function it displays the first node's value only .
please help me what to fix in my code ?

Here is the code :
  class.h file

```
    NumberList::NumberList(){
        head=nullptr;
}

void NumberList::appendNode(double num){

    ListNode *newNode;
    ListNode *nodeptr;

    newNode=new ListNode;
    newNode->value=num;
    newNode->next=nullptr;

    if(!head){
        head=newNode;
    }
    else{
        nodeptr=head;
        while(nodeptr->next){
            nodeptr=nodeptr->next;

            nodeptr->next=newNode;

        }
    }
}

    void NumberList::insertNode(double num){
    ListNode *newNode;
    ListNode *nodeptr;
    ListNode *previousNode;
    newNode=new ListNode;
    newNode->value=num;
    if(!head){
        head=newNode;
        newNode->next=nullptr;
    }
    else{
        nodeptr=head;
        previousNode=nullptr;
        while(nodeptr!=nullptr&&nodeptr->value<num){
            previousNode=nodeptr;
            nodeptr=nodeptr->next;
        }
        if(previousNode==NULL){
            previousNode=newNode;
            newNode->next=nodeptr;
        }
        else{
            previousNode=newNode;
            newNode->next=nodeptr;
        }
    }
}

void NumberList::DeleteNode(double num){

    ListNode *nodeptr;
    ListNode *previousNode = nullptr;
    if(!head){
        return;
    }

    if(head->value==num){
        nodeptr=head->next;
        delete head;
        head=nodeptr;
    }
    else{
        nodeptr=head;
        while(nodeptr!=NULL&&nodeptr->value!=num){
            previousNode=nodeptr;
            nodeptr=nodeptr->next;
        }
        if(nodeptr){
            previousNode->next=nodeptr->next;
            delete nodeptr;
        }


    }

}

    void NumberList::DisplayNode()const{
        ListNode *nodeptr;
        nodeptr=head;
        while(nodeptr){
            cout<<nodeptr->value<<endl;
            nodeptr=nodeptr->next;
        }
    }

NumberList::~NumberList(){}
```

main function:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    NumberList list;

    list.appendNode(0.9);
    list.appendNode(13.9);
    list.DisplayNode();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: The output of the displayNode is only the first value .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think *very* carefully about the code you have for stepping through the list looking for where you can append your new value, especially the last line inside that loop body:

```
while(nodeptr->next){
    nodeptr=nodeptr->next;
    nodeptr->next=newNode;
}
```

Were you to actually single-step your code through a debugger, examining the list after each statement, you would see the problem instantly.